# Need example of WPF Gradiant Picker

Tags: wpf, color-picker, picker

I'm looking for a WPF Gradient Picker example and source code.

The goal is to allow the user of a WPF application to pick the gradient brush to use for a background or foreground.  I've seen pickers in Blend (too confusing for a casual user) and Photo Shop.  I'm looking for a WPF implementation of something along the line of the Photo Shop picker implemented as a WPF dialog box.

Any pointers to good examples much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, this one too on the CodeProject: [.Net Protoshop-like gradient picker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/AdobeGradient.aspx). Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Random gradient wallpaper generator](http://wallpaper.codeplex.com/). closest thing I could find... unfortunately it only has four possible gradient stops, one in each corner... worth looking at the code perhaps, and getting a few tips...

Comment: Thanks.  This code may be something that can serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something that would be pretty easy to code, in terms of a custom control.

Just have a canvas that you change the background of, with some other controls for changing the colour and the stop points.